# node-mongodb-native or Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

We are going to develop an application that will work with MongoDB. The users of the application will create custom entities with the help of the GUI so we don't have any predefined entities while developing the application. Should we go with mongodb-native or use Mongoose?

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean mongodb-native? :-)

Comment: I'm being a bit snarky and saying it's hard to give a specific answer either way.  If you find you need to reuse entities and validate them - you might find mongoose helpful.  Or if things are very dynamic, mongoose might be be a bit overkill.  It will depend as well on how you need to query the data later.  Bonne chance mademoiselle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan on using predefined entities or "schema" don't use Mongoose.
I suggest using a wrapper around the native driver, such as https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin , it does everything the native driver is doing, but much simpler.